# Copper corrosion, well water

Tags: water, well, copper, corrosion

My well water pH is 7.06 as measured by an accurate and calibrated tool used for wine making. I have around 15 gpg of hardness. My question is why I am getting between .5 - 1.0 mg/L of copper in my water. I measured the copper where the water enters the house and it was 0.0 (no copper pipes outside house). Inside is a different story. It is below the EPA action level of 1.3 mg/L but I'd rather not have any copper corrosion. With a pH of 7 and the hardness level I have would this indicate something wrong besides water chemistry? Electrolysis?

Also, when the water softener was activated the problem was way worse. Bypassing the softener brought the copper levels down. This makes me think it is a water chemistry issue.

Comment: Did you flush the pipes before measuring the copper? It may just be that the water sat in the pipes for a long time and that's why the copper was so high. Otherwise, it's likely to be electrolysis.

Comment: I did flush the pipes. They are used often throughout the day. With electrolysis I guess I have to go crawling through the attic looking for metal on metal contact...

Comment: @user64440 - metal on metal contact on the outside of the pipe is not going to create the problem.  It's only an issue with dissimilar metals connected electrically and both in contact with the water.

Comment: Softeners can cause copper sulfates a third type of pitting in copper pipes.  If you can examine the pipe inner wall and it is a nice bright blue color your softener is the likely issue.  Try turning it off for a week or so and test again.

Comment: Are you chlorinating in any form? If so, how much and how?

Comment: @Tyson I am not chlorinating at all

Comment: My softener has been off for over a month to isolate this issue. I am going to electrically disconnect my recirculation pump which has been off for years but is always ticking (current). Just a guess at this point.

Comment: How new are the copper pipes?  It takes some time for new copper to develop a protective layer.  Also, did you measure both hot and cold water levels?

Comment: @Mark the pipes are 15 years old. I first noticed the problem 3 years ago after installing a 3 stage whole house filter (not reverse osmosis though). The slight blue tinge could have been more noticeable with cleaner water and the issue could predate this event...

Comment: Another theory I just though about... My well booster pump is oversized for some reason (according to the well company). I think it it operates at around 50 GPM pulling from a storage tank. This exceeds the max water velocity for 3/4" copper. I have heard this can cause copper to break down.